# Pasarela de Pago Cybersource en PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Resulta que estoy intentando resolver una problemática con la integración de la pasarela de pago Cybersource para hacer transacciones con visanet. Pero me arroja el siguiente error cuando ejecuto el pago:

```
"SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://ics2wsa.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.26.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://ics2wsa.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.26.wsdl"
```

Lo estoy implementando en Wordpress, pero sin ningun plugin, solo con codigo PHP en la version 5.6, me estoy guiando de este ejemplo:
https://github.com/CyberSource/cybersource-soap-toolkit/blob/master/sample_php/web-sample.php
Pero no he logrado resolver el error.
Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues está diciendo que no puede procesar ese archivo WSDL. Por favor haz clic en el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/373283/edit) que esta bajo tu pregunta y añade el código relevante a la pregunta (lo que escribiste para consumir el web service). Recuerda no incluir credenciales de entornos productivos ni nigún otro dato sensible; reemplázalo con valores de ejemplo.

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta rápidamente. El código se comparte como texto pensando en que acá las personas se toman el trabajo de replicar los errores que reportamos y replicar desde una imagen es harto aburrido

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21973010/236345) en SO en inglés, puede que

a) tu mensaje no tenga el user-agent
b) tu servidor esté resolviendo la URL a IPv6 y no a IPv4

EN la respuesta citada instancian el SoapClient y le mandan las opciones. Tú estás extendiéndolo pero debería usar los métodos de la superclase tal cual (no uso PHP hace rato, espero que así sea)

```
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$wsdlUrl = 'http://URL/para/el/archivo.wsdl';
$soapClientOptions = array(
    'stream_context' => $context,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
);

$client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soapClientOptions);
```

Para lo segundo, habría que revisar la configuración del servidor.